# Реализация пользовательской коллекции

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Мне необходимо реализовать класс-коллекцию для хранения элементов, имеющих уникальный составной ключ [Id, Name] (Id и Name – компоненты ключа, могу быть произвольного типа). При этом можно использовать любую встроенную коллекцию .NET.

Прошу ваших замечаний, предложений, правильно ли я реализовал задачу?, если нет, то как правильно реализовать данную задачу?

```
namespace ItemsCollection
{

    public class UserType
    {
        private int Id { get; set; }
        private string Name { get; set; }

        public UserType(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Id.GetHashCode(); 
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var second = obj as UserType;

            if (second == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (this.Id == second.Id) && (this.Name == second.Name);
        }


    }

   public class SpecDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
   {

   }







    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SpecDictionary<UserType, string> specDict = new SpecDictionary<UserType, string>();

            specDict.Add(new UserType(1, "A"), "Петров");

            specDict.Add(new UserType(2, "B"), "Иванов");


            Console.WriteLine(specDict[(new UserType(1, "A"))]);


            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Тестовое задание в 2ГИС? ;)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: откуда вы знакомы с тестовыми в 2гис? )

Comment: Vladimir, даже если вы хотите решить задачу самостоятельно, удалять существующие решения ни в коем случае нельзя. Во-первых, вы удаляете код, на который автор потратил свое время. Во-вторых, это делает ответ менее полезным для будущих читателей.

Comment: Аналогично с вопросом. Без кода он становится бессмысленным. Вы спрашиваете, правильно ли реализовали задачу, но реализации-то нет. Я вернул оба сообщения к исходному состоянию.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну, мне самому такое когда-то выдавали. К своему стыду могу сказать, что мое решение тогда было очень плохим, уж не знаю насколько это лучше :).

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: так вы там работали тоже?

Comment: @NickVolynkin о нет, меня не взяли! Нехорошие! :)

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: кстати, не хотите ли принять участие вот в этом? http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/883/181472. Можно, например, в НГУ устроить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin смотя в каком виде. Как посетитель - теоретически возможно, как лектор/организатор - не тот уровень знаний/умений. И в любом случае не так много свободного времени, как хотелось бы. Если вам это интересно, то думаю стоит обратится в тот же 2ГИС, я недавно был на одном из их мероприятий DevDays. Организация превосходная, к тому же они тоже активно ищут ораторов. Я думаю это идеальный вариант на данный момент в плане качества, охвата и т.д.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: с 2ГИС нам сначала надо бы другой вопрос решить ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачу вы решили неправильно, попробуйте добавить `UserType UserKey4 = new UserType(34, "Петров");` - т.е. дубликат. Дубликат добавится, что противоречит уникальности ключа. Это следствие того что вы сравниваете объекты просто по ссылке, а не по содержимому.

Что касается вашего второго вопроса, то правильная реализация задачи предполагает сравнение компонентов ключа по содержимому. Собственно в этом и есть основная сложность и суть задачи. Сразу скажу вам, что решение для `N` компонетов ключа будет предпочтительным. Из типовых подходов для решения может быть использование Reflection для "глубокого" сравнения произвольных объектов, либо перевод объекта в форму удобную для сравнения (например сериализация в строку и сравнение строк).

Перевод в строку на мой взгляд предпочтительнее т.к. он позволит вам использовать быстрые контейнеры типа Dictionary без дополнительных трудозатрат:

```
public class ComplexKeyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, TValue> _internalStore = new Dictionary<string, TValue>();
    private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        var keyStr = SerializeKey(key);
        _internalStore.Add(keyStr, value);
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        var keyStr = SerializeKey(key);
        return _internalStore.Remove(keyStr);
    }

    public TValue Get(TKey key)
    {
        var keyStr = SerializeKey(key);
        return _internalStore[keyStr];
    }

    private string SerializeKey(TKey obj)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            _serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class UserType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var testTarget = new ComplexKeyDictionary<UserType, string>();
        testTarget.Add(new UserType { Id = 1, Name = "1" }, "one");
        testTarget.Add(new UserType { Id = 2, Name = "2" }, "two");
        testTarget.Add(new UserType { Id = 3, Name = "3" }, "three");
        testTarget.Add(new UserType { Id = 4, Name = "4" }, "four");
        testTarget.Remove(new UserType { Id = 3, Name = "3" });

        Console.WriteLine("Got 1 ?: {0}", testTarget.Get(new UserType { Id = 1, Name = "1" }));
        Console.WriteLine("Got 2 ?: {0}", testTarget.Get(new UserType { Id = 2, Name = "2" }));
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got 3 ?: {0}", testTarget.Get(new UserType { Id = 3, Name = "3" }));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got 3 ?: failed");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Got 4 ?: {0}", testTarget.Get(new UserType { Id = 4, Name = "4" }));
        try
        {
            testTarget.Add(new UserType {Id = 4, Name = "4"}, "four dup");
            Console.WriteLine("Can add duplicate!");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding duplicate failed");
        }
        testTarget.Add(new UserType { Id = 3, Name = "3" }, "three");

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! про то, что неправильно и получается дубликат уже сам догадался.

Comment: Посмотрел примеры выше, вижу что при реализации                         var specDict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, string>();
 specDict.Add(Tuple.Create(1, "А"), "Парковка"); классы UserType SpecDictionary<T> вообще не нужны! не правильно это.

Comment: @Vladimir Tuple достаточно тяжело смотряться в коде, значения неименованы - легко забыть что в них первое значение, что - второе (особенно если тип одинаковый).  так что я бы рекомендовал все-таки UserType вместо Tuple

Comment: Я бы вообще на вашем месте не акцентировался на вашем `UserType` - это должен быть аргумент типа дженерика. Т.е. ваш класс должен выглядеть как `SpecDictionary<TKey, TValue>` где `TKey` - ключ произвольного типа.

Comment: т.е.  `public class SpecDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
   { }` а дальше TKey может быть UserType ??

Comment: А зачем вообще наследование? Просто `public class SpecDictionary<TKey, TValue>` где `TKey` это `UserType`.

Comment: наследовать методы

Comment: И зачем? Какая вам от этого польза? У вас вся суть в том, что стандартные методы у вас не работают, надо делать свои.

Comment: Petr Abdulin, т.е. прибавление в коллекцию должно осуществлять не в таком формате  `specDict.Add(new UserType(1, "A"), "Петров");` а в таком                                                                                            `specDict.Add(1, "A", "Петров");` ??

Comment: Нет. Просто я не вижу смысла в наследовании. Добавил пример реализации того что я имел в виду.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Данное решение не подходит в общем случае, т.к. накладываются ограничения на ключ. Не все объекты можно однозначно сравнить с помощъю reflection, и тем более не все объекты можно преобразовать в строку с сохранением отношения эквивалентности. Это будет работать только для действительно простых типов - кортежей простых значений, с которыми справится и Tuple.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin а требование на сериализуемость стандартным XmlSerializer настолько строгое,  что является практически антонимом понятия "любой тип". Хотя, может быть в этой конкретной конторе ждут именно такого решения.

Comment: @PashaPash в данном решении нет ограничений на ключ. Другое дело что не с любым ключом это будет работать, у всего есть свои пределы. Не путайте решение написаное за 10 мин на коленке в качестве примера с продакшен кодом.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin да, согласен, просто если человек пойдет на собеседование - он должен знать возможные ограничения "своего" решения, и знать что можно ответить "ваше задание не решабельно в общем случае, но для частных есть вот такая реализация"

Answer (score 4):

Ваша реализация UserType не поддерживает проверку на эквивалентность. Т.е. следующий код выдаст исключение "ключ не найден":

```
var specDict = new SpecDictionary<string>();
specDict.Add(new UserType(24, "Иванов"), "Some");
Console.WriteLine(specDict.Find(new UserType(24, "Иванов")));
```

Dictionary, как и почти все стандартные классы в .NET, проверяет объекты на эквивалентность в три стадии:

- сравнивается адрес объекта в памяти - значение двух ссылок. Если обе ссылки равны, то объекты считаются эквивалентными (т.к. это реально один объект).
- сравнивается значение результатов вызова `GetHashCode` для объектов - краткого числового представления. Если HashCode разный - объекты считаются разными.
- если HashCode совпал - вызывается метод `obj.Equals(obj)`

Собственно, вам нужно переопределить `GetHashCode` и `Equals`

```
public class UserType
{
    private int Id { get; set; }
    private string Name { get; set; }

    public UserType(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode(); // или Id.GetHashCode() ^ name.GetHashCode()
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var second = obj as UserType;

        if (second == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return (this.Id == second.Id) && (this.Name == second.Name);
    }
}
```

и код в примере выше заработает.

**UP:**

Если вам нужен стандартный спосов сравнивать "наборы" ключей - вам стоит использовать класс [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) в качестве ключа:

```
var specDict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>,string>();

specDict.Add(Tuple.Create(24, "Иванов"), "Some");
Console.WriteLine(specDict[(Tuple.Create(24, "Иванов"))]); // Some
```

Comment: Данное решение не подходит в общем случае, т.к. накладываются ограничения на ключ.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin какие еще ограничения на ключ?

Comment: Вы предполагаете, что ключ должен что-то реализовывать. Хотя в задании ключ просто объект с парой полей произвольных типов.

Comment: Если класс ключа менять нельзя, то надо реализовать интерфейс `IEqualityComparer<>` для передачи в конструктор словаря.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin всегда можно скопировать переданный пользовательский ключ во внутренний неизменяемый тип. То, что объект не должен меняться пока используется в качестве ключа - это ограничение реализации топикастера, а не моей.

Comment: @PashaPash я вообще не это имел в виду, а то что `UserType` это вообще "внешний" тип по отношению к коллекции. Его определит пользователь коллекции.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin тогда общего решения нет. потому что понятие "эквивалентности" в общем виде не определено. Некоторые простые случаи можно обработать через наследование Dictionary с передачей кастомного `IEqualityComparer<>` в базовый конструктор - примерно то, что в вашем ответе, но без переопределения всех методов.

Comment: @PashaPash я соглашусь. Но это просто другая задача "напишите тип который позволит использовать его в стандартном `Dictionary` в качестве ключа". Тут вся суть чтобы написать максимально универсальный класс-коллекцию где можно будет использовать составной ключ. Я кстати не готов сказать что моё решение самое лучшее или более того правильное в понимании постановщика задачи. Но ваше решение подходит совсем с другой стороны в моём понимании задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Если отбросить ваш пример и посмотреть на условие, то имеем утверждения:

1. Объект ключа может иметь любой тип.
2. Объект ключа должен иметь два открытых Поля/Свойства: Id и Name

Решение задачи основываем на том, что для любой встроенной коллекции в .Net можно установить внешний объект, занимающийся сравнением (Comparer). А так же, что ключ объектов рассматриваем как тип Object, т.е. любой тип может стать ключом.

Далее при сравнении ключей при помощи reflection или dynamic получаем значения Id и Name у пары объектов ключей и сравниваем их.

```
class Comparer : System.Collections.IComparer, 
                 System.Collections.IEqualityComparer,
                 System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<Object>,
                 System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<Object>
{
    int System.Collections.IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return this.Compar(x, y) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    bool System.Collections.IEqualityComparer.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return this.Compar(x, y);
    }

    int System.Collections.IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int IComparer<object>.Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return this.Compar(x, y) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    bool System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<Object>.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return this.Compar(x, y);
    }

    int System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<Object>.GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    private Boolean Compar(object x, object y)
    {
        dynamic dx = x;
        dynamic dy = y;

        return Object.Equals(dx.Id, dy.Id) && Object.Equals(dx.Name, dy.Name);
    }
}
```

Пример:

```
public class Key1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Key1(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Key2
{
    public Object Id;
    public Object Name;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<Object, String> dictionary = new Dictionary<Object, String>(new Comparer());

    Key1 key1 = new Key1(1, "Name");

    dictionary.Add(key1, "Hello");

    Key2 key2 = new Key2() { Id = 1, Name = "Name" };

    Console.WriteLine(dictionary.ContainsKey(key2)); // true
}
```